# howto autoref individual equations in an eqnarray

Tags: eqnarray

Hi I have the following latex written:

```
They are given as follows by \autoref{maxwelleq1, maxwelleq2, maxwelleq3, maxwelleq4} \cite{maxwellfour}.

\begin{eqnarray}
\label{maxwelleq1}
\text{Gauss' Law:}& \displaystyle \oint_{\partial \Sigma}^{}\vec{E}\cdot\dA&=\frac{Q_{enc}}{\eps0}\\
\label{maxwelleq2}
\text{Gauss' Law for Magnetism:}& \displaystyle \oint_{\partial \Sigma }^{}\vec{B}\cdot\dA&=0\\
\label{maxwelleq3}
\text{Maxwell-Faraday Equation:}& \displaystyle\oint{\vec{E}\cdot\ds}&=-\frac{\dphib}{\dt}\\
\label{maxwelleq4}
\text{Ampère's Law:}& \displaystyle\oint{\vec{B}\cdot\ds}&=\muz\eps0\frac{\dphie}{\dt}+\muz i_{enc}
\end{eqnarray}
```

Which results in a good equation array. However, I cannot figure how to reference each equation in a group, shown on the first line. I'm after something like "as follows by Equations(1,2,3,4).

Is this possible? Secondly what am I missing to accomplish this?

Comment: Please make your sniplet into a full minimal example. For example what is `\dA`, `\eps`, `\muz`???? And using `eqnarray` is not recommended

Comment: Plus `\autoref` does not support lists of keys. Perhaps you should have a look at what `cleveref` can do instead.

Comment: Would you mind posting a *compilable* and *complete* code?